# Selenide-selenium StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenide

I have to open all links in the page, and then check if it has the text ("No info") or not.

I used Selenide v3.5 and Selenium v2.53 libraries. However, I have this exception "StaleElementReferenceException".

my code as following:

```
    open(url);
        WebDriverRunner.clearBrowserCache();

        WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> linksize = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        linksCount = linksize.size();
        links = new String[linksCount];
        Common.consoleOutput.printMessage(String.format("Total no of links Available: %d", linksCount));

        for (int i = 0; i < linksCount; i++)
        {
            links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");

        }
        // navigate to each Link on the webpage
        for (int i = 0; i < linksCount; i++) {
            WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().navigate().to(url_arabic);
            WebElement error = $(Selectors.byText("No info"));
            $(error).shouldNotBe(visible).shouldNotBe(text("No info"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use web-element wrapping:

```
WebElement error = $(Selectors.byText("No info"));
$(error).shouldNotBe(visible).shouldNotBe(text("No info"));
```

Try use selector wrapping directly:

```
$(Selectors.byText("No info")).shouldNotBe(visible).shouldNotBe(text("No info"));
```

Its should help. I not recommend using `$(WebElement)`, because, selenide perform re-search element. if element is not found in first time, And getting correct selector from WebElement is difficult by selenium design.

Comment: Thank you but still didn't work for firefox 45.0.1
I remove this part from code and still give the exception.
I remove all code after for (int i = 0; i < linksCount; i++)
        {
            links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");

        }

Comment: error trace point the cause of this exception to this line
    links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I used the following code to get the link elements:

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SelenideElement link : $$("a"))
            links.add(link.attr("href"));
```

instead of

```
        List<WebElement> linksize = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```